# How can I 301 redirect a url using htaccess with additional full stops in it?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a set of urls that have been flagged up by Webmaster Tools that go something like this:-

`www.domain.com/blog/tag/tag-name/www.whatisthisdomaindoinghere.com/subdir/subsubdir/index.htm`

I just don't know how to redirect these to fairly simple domains like www.domain.com.

Help appreciated greatly :-)
Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/.+ /blog/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: OK - hands up - I don't really know what I'm doing with this, though it looks really potentially useful! Can you elaborate on exactly what this does so I can apply it to the various redirects of this kind I need to setup please? Thanks :-)

Comment: @user3329728 it makes sure the request is for the host `www.domain.com`, then it matches `/blog/something/anything/everything-else` and redirects to `/blog/something/anything/`, essentially removing the "everything-else" part

Comment: ok thanks. does that mean that if I apply this redirect rule to my site then ANY blog entry that is /something/anything/everything-else deep will have the /everything-else removed and stripped back to /something/anything? if so then that will not work as it effects the blog site wide :-( I do appreciate your help.

Comment: @user3329728 yes, it'll remove everythign, if you want to only remove something specific, then you need to replace the `.+` at the end with exactly what it is you want removed

Comment: so if the something specific is:-

www.whatisthisdomaindoinghere.com/subdir/subsubdir/index.htm (see example above)

then do I want the code to be:-

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/www.whatisthisdomaindoinghere.com/subdir/subsubdir/index.htm /blog/$1/$2/ [L,R=301]`

or is that just far too simplistic?!